# Как убрать запятую если в поле остается или является единственным значением подстрока для замены

Tags: sql

Есть таблица

```
user_id | article_id | list_ids
```

В поле хранятся слова\цифры или слова с цифрами разделенные знаком нижнего подчеркивания, например: `1,d_5,6,d7675765`

Нужно убрать одно из знаний из поля например `d_5`
Делаю так:

```
UPDATE `table` SET  `list_ids` = REPLACE(`list_ids` , 'd_5', '') WHERE concat(',',list_ids,',') LIKE '%,d_5,%'
```

Но как сделать так чтобы если значение в поле имеет запятую с права или лева, то нужно удалять запятую, чтобы в поле не получилось: `,d_5`, `d_5,` и др, а только

`d_5`, `d_5,6`, `6,d_5` и др

Например:

Было в поле: `1,d_5,6,d7675765`

Стало в поле: `1,6,d7675765`

---

Было в поле: `d_5,6,d7675765`

Стало в поле: `6,d7675765`

---

Было в поле: `d_5`

Стало в поле: `пусто`

---

Было в поле: `6, d_5`

Стало в поле: `6`

Comment: последовательно выполнить три команды?) %,d_5,% // d_5,% // %,d_5

Comment: Может структуру таблицы еще не поздно поменять (не много кода ее использует) и нормализовать ее, т.е. не хранить список через запятую, а держать каждое значение в отдельной строке. иначе вы намучаетесь еще со всеми этими изменениями, потому что SQL в принципе не предназначен для работы с данными в таком формате.

Comment: А я бы всетаки переложил эту задачу с базы на приложение. Что-нибудь вроде explode по запятой, удаляем нужный элемент массива и потом implode в строку. И уже так пишем в базу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как сделать так чтобы если значение в поле имеет запятую с права или лева, то нужно удалять запятую, чтобы в поле не получилось: ,d_5, d_5, и др

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET  `list_ids` = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', `list_ids`, ','), ',d_5,', ','))
WHERE INSTR(list_ids, 'd_5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код, с примерами работает.

*Обратите внимание на то что код удаляет запятые с одним пробелом с права:*

```
update ТАБЛИЦА
set КОЛОНКА=REGEXP_REPLACE(КОЛОНКА, ', |( *d_5[[:punct:]]*)', '')
```

> Было:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Стало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по обратным апострофам в коде в вопросе, это MySQL в котором нет функции regexp_replace

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET  `list_ids` = trim(both ',' from replace(replace(list_ids,'d_5',''),',,',','))
WHERE concat(',',list_ids,',') LIKE '%,d_5,%'
```

Comment: из значения `d_56,d_5,4,4,5` получается `6,4,4,5` потому что при замене нет контроля на наличие запятых

Comment: Согласен. Пример был нерепрезентативный. :-)